# What is the difference between an hour’s commute to work and a two hour drive to work?

Tags: nouns

Why can’t I use an hour commute to work or two hours drive to work.If the word drive in the phrase a two hour drive is a countable noun how is it counted? Please explain

Comment: How about adding some reference?

Comment: Who says you can't? If you have _an hour's commute_, it takes you an hour to travel to work. If you have _a two-hour drive_, it takes you 2 hours to drive yourself there. _A drive_ is a period of driving.